# Screen resolution of a VM using RDP with TestComplete

Tags: teamcity, virtual-machine, resolution, testcomplete

To test our desktop application we have a Master project that runs the Slave project on different VMs.
We are using TeamCity to start our tests. On a TestManagement machine (VM) we have a Build Agent that is running as Service. This Build Agent starts the Master project with TestExecute.

This project connects with RDP to different VM to run our UI Tests (Slave project) of our App. We are using Network Suite and run our tests on Hosts (VMs) like it is suggest here: Using Network Suite.

But we have an issue with the screen resolution that is used to run our UI Tests. The resolution is too low.
This page Running tests via RDP  gives an explanation:

"When running tests on a remote computer that participates in distributed testing, TestComplete creates a Remote Desktop session and automatically sets the master computer's screen resolution on the remote computer. This is done to avoid possible problems with test running."

So TestExecute will use the master computer's screen resolution.
But TeamCity Agent is run as a service on a VM (TestManagement machine) and there is no screen resolution because it's an headless machine and not like a real user that will connect with RDP to this VM and start the Master Project.

I assume TestExecute will then use the default screen resolution (something like 640x480) as the resolution for the RDP connection. But this is too low to run our tests, some object are not on the screen and we have many issues...

**Is there a way to change the resolution used by the RDP connection that TestExecute / TestComplete will create ?** 
The tricky part is that the Master project is started from a service on an headless machine...

Thank you for your answers,

Camille

Answer (score 0):

In the past, we experienced a similar problem as yours and we were unable to solve it by this way. As solution (right now working for us) we installed into our test environments the TightVNC. This able us to forget the screen connection (RDP issues) because you configure the screen resolution by RDP the first time, then access via IP, log in and you will be able to launch whatever you want without open any application. 
Maybe its not the best solution but for our testing environments we can launch tests from Jenkins on demand without screen resolution problems.